# WS Policy with Apache CXF 3.0

Tags: soap, wsdl, cxf

Trying to implement `WS-Policy` within `WSDL`.

**There is my configurations:**

`WS-Policy` within `WSDL`:

```
    <wsp:Policy wsu:Id="Signature">
        <wsp:ExactlyOne>
            <wsp:All>
                <sp:AsymmetricBinding>
                    <wsp:Policy>
                        <sp:InitiatorToken>
                            <wsp:Policy>
                                <sp:X509Token sp:IncludeToken=
                                                      "http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702/IncludeToken/AlwaysToRecipient">
                                    <wsp:Policy>
                                        <sp:WssX509V3Token10 />
                                    </wsp:Policy>
                                </sp:X509Token>
                            </wsp:Policy>
                        </sp:InitiatorToken>
                        <sp:RecipientToken>
                            <wsp:Policy>
                                <sp:X509Token sp:IncludeToken=
                                                      "http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702/IncludeToken/Never">
                                    <wsp:Policy>
                                        <sp:WssX509V3Token10 />
                                    </wsp:Policy>
                                </sp:X509Token>
                            </wsp:Policy>
                        </sp:RecipientToken>
                        <sp:AlgorithmSuite>
                            <wsp:Policy>
                                <sp:TripleDesRsa15/>
                            </wsp:Policy>
                        </sp:AlgorithmSuite>
                        <sp:Layout>
                            <wsp:Policy>
                                <sp:LaxTsFirst />
                            </wsp:Policy>
                        </sp:Layout>
                        <sp:IncludeTimestamp />
                        <sp:OnlySignEntireHeadersAndBody />
                    </wsp:Policy>
                </sp:AsymmetricBinding>
                <sp:SignedParts>
                    <sp:Body />
                </sp:SignedParts>
            </wsp:All>
        </wsp:ExactlyOne>
    </wsp:Policy>
```

`CXF` configuration:

```
    EndpointImpl endpoint = new EndpointImpl(bus, service);
    endpoint.setWsdlLocation("classpath:/wsdl/ws.wsdl");
    endpoint.setProperties(new HashMap<String, Object>() {
        {
            put("ws-security.signature.validator", customSignatureValidator);
            put("ws-security.signature.properties", new Properties() {{
                put("org.apache.ws.security.crypto.provider", "org.apache.ws.security.components.crypto.Merlin");
                put("org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.type", "jks");
                put("org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.password", keystorePassword);
                put("org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.file", keystorePath);
            }});
            put("ws-security.signature.username", privateKeyName);
            put("ws-security.callback-handler", (CallbackHandler) callbacks -> {
                WSPasswordCallback passwordCallback = (WSPasswordCallback) callbacks[0];

                passwordCallback.setPassword(privateKeyPassword);
            });
        }
    });
    endpoint.publish("/ws");
```

**Problem:**

After sending `SOAP` request with timestamp, signature key information etc. I'm getting `SOAP` fault message:

```
    These policy alternatives can not be satisfied: 
    {http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702}AsymmetricBinding: Received Timestamp does not match the requirements
    {http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702}InitiatorToken
    {http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702}RecipientToken
    {http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702}IncludeTimestamp
    {http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702}OnlySignEntireHeadersAndBody
```

Error appears even if I'm not sending timestamp. According logs (`CXF`) I see that signature is correct.

Comment: Goal, configurations, error messages - What is your question? (Oh, and please use a _block quote_ for error messages (precede with `> ` instead of four spaces; append two spaces where a line break shall be kept).)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some debugging and experiments figured out the problem: provided SOAP request was incorrect according `WS-Policy`: `Timestamp` and `Body` must be signed by the same signature. If signed only `Body` - will face listed errors (which are bit inaccurate).